# Accessing copied version of an object to modify?

Tags: javascript

If I copy code into a closure like this

```
(function(){
    var private1 = {},
        private2 = {},
        publik;

    publik.get(object){
         private1[object.name] = object;
    };

    window.publik = publik;
}())


publik.get({
    // API
    name: 'name_foo',
    functionA: function(){
        // I can not access private2 in here
    },
    functionB: function(){}
})
```

Is there a way the API can work, so that the functionA and functionB can have access to private 2 inside the closure.

They will be copied into the closure, so the copied version should have access to it.  That is why I made the closure and put private1 and private2 together like that.

The written version ( not the copied version ) of the object throws an error in jslint and my guess is that this is becasue it breaks scope rules.

The function argument ( not parameter ) is an un-named variable in the global scope and has no access to the closure.

( until is is copied into it :)

Would it work if I made `private1` and `private 2` the same object say...just `private`...and then accessed it using `this` keyword.

**I would prefer to keep them separate however.**

Comment: You can not access private1 and private2 directly from functionA or functionB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors and *get* seems to be better named as *set*. Also, your code doesn't seem to be specific to browsers, so better to use the more generic *global* object than the specific *window* object.

Consider something like:

```
(function(global){
    var private1 = {name: 'private1'},
        private2 = {name: 'private2'},
        publik;

    publik = {
      set: function (object) {
        private1[object.name] = object;
      }
    };

    global.publik = publik;
}(this))
```

The *publik.set* method has access to *private1* and *private2* through a closure, you can access them through privileged methods as explained by Douglas Crockford in his article [Private Members in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html). Extending the above, it might be:

```
    publik = {

      set : function (...) {
        ...
      },

      getPrivate1: function (name) {
        return (typeof name == 'string')? private1[name] : private1;
      },

      ...

    };
```

Comment: I can't add much that isn't in the referenced Crockford article. I guess you're looking for a way to add privileged methods after the object has been initialised, I'm sure there's a pattern to do that but not sure if it's useful. :-/

Comment: Thanks...was tired when I got stuck on this...this is your basic getter/setter that is CS 101 when you use a compiled language.  Thanks!